# \frac not working in align

Tags: align, fractions

I'm trying to write "T(n/3)" within an align block, but I'm not getting the behavior I expect. When I enter this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}

    T(n) = 3T(\frac{n}{3}) + 2n -3

\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I get this output from Overleaf:

[image: Everything after the \frac gets put in the denominator of the fraction]

I didn't get this issue when I used aligns and fracs before in the same document. For example, this one worked just as intended:

```
\begin{align}
S &= \frac{1}{2} + &\frac{1}{4} + &\frac{2}{8} +&\frac{3}{16} + &\frac{5}{32} + &\frac{8}{64} + &\frac{13}{128} + \dots\\
\frac{1}{2}S &= &\frac{1}{4} + &\frac{1}{8} + &\frac{2}{16} +&\frac{3}{32} + &\frac{5}{64} + &\frac{8}{128} + \dots\\
S-\frac{1}{2}S &= \frac{1}{2}+ &\frac{0}{4} + &\frac{1}{8} + &\frac{1}{16} +&\frac{2}{32} + &\frac{3}{64} + &\frac{5}{128} + \dots\\
&= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{S}{4}\\
&\implies 4S-2S=2+S\\
&\implies S=2
\end{align}
```

yielding:

[image: \frac in align that works properly]

Comment: I cannot reproduce your behavior with the syntax you provide.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin I added one, thanks for letting me know

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I added a MWE to make it easier to run

Comment: if you get an error please ask about the error (by design the typeset pdf is essentially nonsense after any error so showing the printed output is not so useful) If you scroll past an error tex's recovery aims to help debugging but makes no attempt at sensible output.

Comment: As stated in the answer by @AlessandroCuttin `align` is part of the `amsmath` package so you need `\usepackage{amsmath}`. Also, remove the empty lines inside the `align` environment. An empty line is a new paragraph, which is not appreciated in mathmode.

Comment: I can reproduce the output by only adding `\usepackage{amsmath}` and skipping errors. Of course, the issue are the blank lines inside `align`, that are not allowed and raise low level errors.

Answer (score 1):

What about the following?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        S &= \frac{1}{2} + &\frac{1}{4} + &\frac{2}{8} +&\frac{3}{16} + &\frac{5}{32} + &\frac{8}{64} + &\frac{13}{128} + \dots\\
        \frac{1}{2}S &= &\frac{1}{4} + &\frac{1}{8} + &\frac{2}{16} +&\frac{3}{32} + &\frac{5}{64} + &\frac{8}{128} + \dots\\
        S-\frac{1}{2}S &= \frac{1}{2}+ &\frac{0}{4} + &\frac{1}{8} + &\frac{1}{16} +&\frac{2}{32} + &\frac{3}{64} + &\frac{5}{128} + \dots\\
        &= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{S}{4}\\
        &\implies 4S-2S=2+S\\
        &\implies S=2\\
        T(n) &= 3T\left(\frac{n}{3}\right) + 2n -3
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

with respect to your MWE I added the `amsmath` package, and improved the brackets by using `\left` and `\right`, which gives me:

[image]